# Flutter app is having Gradleexception error . w

Tags: flutter, gradle

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the path of the flutter sdk in your ./android/local.properties file :

flutter.sdk="path_to_flutter"

Comment: dont mind me asking . how do i do that? sorry im new to all this.

Comment: Find the local.properties file in your project and set the value I showed to you

Comment: hi there. i am truly sorry but i am a noob at this. is there a step by step instruction on how i can do that ?

Comment: You can find here everything you need to know https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install
Click on your Operating system and follow the instructions... upvote for an answer plz

Comment: hi there. but what if i already have flutter in my operating system. i already downloaded it and have already started using flutter. d i have to go through the instructions again?

Comment: Show me your local.properties file please

Comment: sorry but how do i get that?

Comment: is this what you are looking for?                                 Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

Comment: as I said, this file is on the `android` folder of your project

Comment: sdk.dir=/Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/macbook/Desktop/flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1

Comment: is that the one ?

Comment: Yes, can you check your Flutter installation path `flutter.sdk=/Users/macbook/Desktop/flutter` ? Is Flutter is installed here ?

Comment: yup .. this is what it says : Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/macbook/Desktop/flutter

Comment: macbook$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132,
    locale en-SG)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at /Users/macbook/Desktop/flutter

Comment: It's a strange issue. If you create a project from scratch with `flutter create my_test`and `flutter run` with an android device or emulator, do it work ?

Comment: i am running it from my ios simulator and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: but despite that  i am still having the same error and i can't run my flutter app.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I don't know how to help you now